# Can a transaction end sucessfully (i.e. not revert state) but some of it's 'traces' run out of gas?

Tags: transactions, contract-debugging

This transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfcf6acee992a6562aeb641fe830b93a6e6c3be9080eb3842909137824d6a7881, has an odd message that I first noticed today:

```
Although one or more errors occurred [Out of gas] contract execution completed
```

If I retrieve the transaction using EtherScan's API, EtherScan does not report it as an error transaction (and, I don't think it was an error transaction). If I look at the traces of the transaction by pulling them from a local node, many of the traces report "out of gas".

I was under the impression that if any part of the transaction ran out of gas, the entire transaction would revert.

**Question:** How is this possible? What happened here? Is this common?

**Note:** I will be more likely to accept the answer if you provide simple, Solidity example of how this can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can happen if a `CALL` is made to another contract. Only a portion of gas is forwarded, and so that call can run out of gas. If the "parent" doesn't revert on the `CALL` failure, then the main transaction can succeed while the call fails due to an out of gas error.

Here's one example of how that can happen. (Call `A.forward(addressOfB)`.)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract A {
    function forward(address to) public payable {
        to.send(msg.value); // only forwards 2300 gas
                            // returns false due to out of gas error
    }
}

contract B {
    uint256 foo;

    function () public payable {
        foo = 3; // not enough gas to SSTORE
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So, the transaction’s `status` field would be 1 (success), but the trace would have an “out of gas”. Is that right?

Comment: I believe that's correct.